# How are session cookies in Typo3 generated?

Tags: cookies, typo3, session-cookies

The Typo3 session cookie `fe_typo_user` is a (seemingly) opaque value consisting of 32 hexadecimal digits. Statistical analysis over large sample of different cookie values shows that their entropy is far below the theoretical maximum of 128 bits.

I couldn't get any obvious information on that: How is `fe_typo_user` generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is generated as a random byte sequence, which is done by the function `getRandomHexString` in [\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility](http://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/current/html/_general_utility_8php_source.html#l01338), which in turn calls the function `generateRandomBytes`, also in [GeneralUtility](http://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/current/html/_general_utility_8php_source.html#l01217). Code of that function:

```
/**
 * Returns a string of highly randomized bytes (over the full 8-bit range).
 *
 * Note: Returned values are not guaranteed to be crypto-safe,
 * most likely they are not, depending on the used retrieval method.
 *
 * @param integer $bytesToReturn Number of characters (bytes) to return
 * @return string Random Bytes
 * @see http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52523
 * @see http://www.php-security.org/2010/05/09/mops-submission-04-generating-unpredictable-session-ids-and-hashes/index.html
 */
static public function generateRandomBytes($bytesToReturn) {
    // Cache 4k of the generated bytestream.
    static $bytes = '';
    $bytesToGenerate = max(4096, $bytesToReturn);
    // if we have not enough random bytes cached, we generate new ones
    if (!isset($bytes[($bytesToReturn - 1)])) {
        if (TYPO3_OS === 'WIN') {
            // Openssl seems to be deadly slow on Windows, so try to use mcrypt
            // Windows PHP versions have a bug when using urandom source (see #24410)
            $bytes .= self::generateRandomBytesMcrypt($bytesToGenerate, MCRYPT_RAND);
        } else {
            // Try to use native PHP functions first, precedence has openssl
            $bytes .= self::generateRandomBytesOpenSsl($bytesToGenerate);
            if (!isset($bytes[($bytesToReturn - 1)])) {
                $bytes .= self::generateRandomBytesMcrypt($bytesToGenerate, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
            }
            // If openssl and mcrypt failed, try /dev/urandom
            if (!isset($bytes[($bytesToReturn - 1)])) {
                $bytes .= self::generateRandomBytesUrandom($bytesToGenerate);
            }
        }
        // Fall back if other random byte generation failed until now
        if (!isset($bytes[($bytesToReturn - 1)])) {
            $bytes .= self::generateRandomBytesFallback($bytesToReturn);
        }
    }
    // get first $bytesToReturn and remove it from the byte cache
    $output = substr($bytes, 0, $bytesToReturn);
    $bytes = substr($bytes, $bytesToReturn);
    return $output;
}
```